# How to define specific .env file to Firebase Deploy using Firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, environment-variables, dotenv

So basically I want to separate my development Firestore Database from my deployment one.

I have create 2 Firebase Projects:

- myapp-dev
- myapp-prod

I have also created 2 .env files:

- .env.development
- .env.production

Firebase Hosting works fine since I am using `firebase use` then I select which one I am hosting the code. The problem is when it comes to Firebase FireStore. Since they are both Firebase projects, when deployed, they are taken as Production.

So is there a way that I can say to Firebase that one project is for development or staging purposes?
Or is there a way to deploy to Firebase forcing my .env.development file?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? running into similar issue

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is not the Firestore, it is the build process and using modules.

Firebase Hosting deploy files in public directory. These files are static or built with webpack etc.

What are you using? (ex. webpack + dotenv, create-react-app, ...)

Please show more detail information. (ex. package.json, firebase.json)

See:

- https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv
- https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables

If you want to deploy using Cloud Build then You can either pass the `--project` flag with firebase command and change .env file each project to copy `.env.production` to `.env` in build process(cloudbuild.yaml).

See:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#source_control_and_firebase_project_aliases
- [Google cloud built not substituting environment variable for firebase token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55754674/google-cloud-built-not-substituting-environment-variable-for-firebase-token/55762821#55762821)
- https://github.com/zkohi/firebase-sub-guides/blob/master/content/docs/ja/cd/index.md#user-content-cloudbuildyaml

Comment: The problem is not the Firebase Project, it is the Firestore. I am using `firebase use` to switch from dev to prod. But when `npm run build` runs, it uses .env.production automatically. The question is how to force `npm run build` to use .env.development

Comment: I edited my answer. I think that the problem is not the Firestore, it is the build process and using modules.