# Cloud Build : Deploying Functions - Error: HTTP Error: 404, Method not found

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build

I want to deploy my Cloud Functions using a CI/CD pipeline (Cloud Build).

Everything is building fine but I'm stuck at this stage:

```
Error: HTTP Error: 404, Method not found.
```

> Note : PROJECT_ID is my real gcloud project id.

```
Starting Step #3 - "deploy function"
Step #3 - "deploy function": Already have image: gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/firebase
Step #3 - "deploy function": ⚠  functions: package.json indicates an outdated version of firebase-functions.
Step #3 - "deploy function":  Please upgrade using npm install --save firebase-functions@latest in your functions directory.
Step #3 - "deploy function": 
Step #3 - "deploy function": === Deploying to 'PROJECT_ID'...
Step #3 - "deploy function": 
Step #3 - "deploy function": i  deploying functions
Step #3 - "deploy function": Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint
Step #3 - "deploy function": 
Step #3 - "deploy function": > functions@ lint /workspace/functions
Step #3 - "deploy function": > tslint --project tsconfig.json
Step #3 - "deploy function": 
Step #3 - "deploy function": no-use-before-declare is deprecated. Since TypeScript 2.9. Please use the built-in compiler checks instead.
Step #3 - "deploy function": Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run build
Step #3 - "deploy function": 
Step #3 - "deploy function": > functions@ build /workspace/functions
Step #3 - "deploy function": > tsc
Step #3 - "deploy function": 
Step #3 - "deploy function": ✔  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
Step #3 - "deploy function": i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
Step #3 - "deploy function": 
Step #3 - "deploy function": Error: HTTP Error: 404, Method not found.
Finished Step #3 - "deploy function"
ERROR
ERROR: build step 3 "gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/firebase" failed: exit status 1
```

I used this git repo as a reference : [cloud builders community - firebase](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/tree/master/firebase)

My **cloudbuild.yaml** is decrypting the firebase token, building a docker image and running the process:

```
steps:
  # Decrypt env secrets
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
    args:
      - kms
      - decrypt
      - --ciphertext-file=.env.enc
      - --plaintext-file=.env
      - --location=global
      - --keyring=cloudbuild-env
      - --key=firebase-token
    id: 'decrypt'
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/firebase', '.']
    id: 'build docker image'
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm
    args: ['install']
    dir: functions
    id: 'functions npm install'
  - name: gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/firebase
    args: ['deploy']
    id: 'deploy functions'
images:
  - gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/firebase
timeout: 600s
```

Now my Dockerfile and my firebase.bash are the same as presented in the git repo:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:8

RUN npm i -g firebase-tools

ADD firebase.bash /usr/bin

RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/firebase.bash

ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/bin/firebase.bash" ]
```

**firebase.bash**

```
#!/bin/bash

# run the original firebase
if [ $FIREBASE_TOKEN ]; then
  firebase "$@" --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN
else
  firebase "$@"
fi
```

I also have a **package.json** to run the deployement (not sure about that):

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions --token \"$FIREBASE_TOKEN\""
  }
}
```

Finally my **firebase.json** looks like this:

```
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ],
    "source": "functions"
  }
}
```

I have enabled the Firebase Admin rôle etc. but still not getting this work :(

Comment: If you have problems deploying your code with the Firebase CLI that don't have specific, actionable error messages, contact Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: I don't know why the 404 error is occurred. But I know the setting sample of Cloud Build using firebase. 
Could you see the following question and try setting? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55754674/google-cloud-built-not-substituting-environment-variable-for-firebase-token/55762821#55762821