# Cannot deploy from GCP Cloud Build to Firebase Hosting

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-hosting, google-cloud-build

I have a repo in a GCP project that containes a PWA that I want to publish in Firebase as a hosting app. I want to setup a trigger so whenever a push is done in a branch it deploys de PWA in Firebase. I've followed the steps in GCP documentation [Deploy Firebase](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-firebase) but I'm always getting what it seems an authorization error

> Failed to get Firebase project ghe-dev-repositories-170-920df. Please make sure the project exists and your account has permission to access it.

I have checked several times that all required APIs are enabled and that @cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com account has the required roles.

I have noticed that when creating the Firebase project, Firebase gave the project an Id distinct than the GCP project. Below I'm pasting the cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
  - name: node
    entrypoint: yarn
    args: ["install"]
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil
    args: ['cp', '${_APP_ENV_PATH}', 'packages/app/.env']
  - name: node
    entrypoint: yarn
    args: ["build"]
  - name: 'gcr.io/${_GCP_PROJECT_ID}/firebase'
    args: ['deploy', '--project=${_TARGET_PROJECT_ID}', '--only=hosting:${_TARGET_ENVIRONMENT}']
timeout: "1600s"
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

Did you run `firebase login:ci` and set the environment variable `FIREBASE_TOKEN`?

See:

- https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools#using-with-ci-systems
- [Google cloud built not substituting environment variable for firebase token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55754674/google-cloud-built-not-substituting-environment-variable-for-firebase-token/55762821#55762821)